# How do I put one image inside another one in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have two images. One is transparent with a bit of opacity, like a shadow, and inside, or top or whatever you call it, I want to put an image that I will use as a button here is my HTML code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(img/fondo.png);
}

div.numero {
  float: left;
}

div.login {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="numero"><img src="img/numero.png" width="600px"></div>
<div class="login">
  <img src="img/sombreado.png" />
  <img src="img/1.png" class="1" />
  <img src="img/2.png" class="2" />
</div>
```

The images 1 and 2 are the two images that I want to use as buttons.

Comment: Please provide a visual as to what you want to happen

Comment: And use lorempixel or placeholder to show images

Comment: Why can you not set the first image as a background?

Comment: Please provide a visual of what you want.. Your question is confusing..

Comment: [this is what i want](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-21-12O0-QHA/TsBacV3pq_I/AAAAAAAAAXM/aUOql7Yjy8k/s1600/Screen+shot+2011-11-13+at+5.01.16+PM.png)

Comment: Your screenshot seems different from your provided code. You only used 2 images, yet there are 5 green and red container-like in the screenshot

Comment: I want ot do that but with ym images, like putting them inside another in  different places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to merge both 1 and 2 on the same place, you should make use of `position` in a clever way for this. You can do it by using:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(img/fondo.png);
}
div.numero {
  float: left;
}
div.login {
  float: right;
}

.login {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.login img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.login img.i-2 {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="numero">
  <img src="//placehold.it/600?text=numero" width="600px" />
</div>
<div class="login">
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=sombreado" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=1" class="i-1" />
  <img src="//placehold.it/100?text=2" class="i-2" />
</div>
```

Make sure you don't give class names with just integers. It won't work.

Comment: I want the images 1 and 2 one next to the other, but inside the image "sombreado"